# Potential Minimum Confusion

Tags: classical-mechanics, potential-energy, conventions, vector-fields, conservative-field

Today my lecturer mentioned the notion of vector field and potential, he also said that if the vector field is a force field then there is a potential energy given by: $F(x)=-\dfrac{dU}{dx}$. (I have not yet gotten into vector calculus and there still a long way until that point). He then gave the example of a harmonic oscillator, more specifically a mass on a spring, where the force is $F=-kx$ where x is the distance from equilibrium point. He then said that you can find the potential energy by doing: $U=-\int F\cdot dx=\int kx=\dfrac{kx^2}{2}+A$ where A is a constant figured out from the the initial conditions. he then gave the example : $U(0)=\dfrac{1}{2} \implies A=\dfrac{1}{2}$

$\therefore U=\dfrac{kx^2}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}$

At this point I am confused since if $x$ is the distance from equilibrium of the mass on the spring shouldn't $U(0)=0$? why is he saying that A can be any constant ? Also in other examples of more complicated systems, the potential minimum is not at zero and at some other point. Shouldn't a system always have the potential minimum at $0$ potential energy?

Comment: Did you know that potential energy can also be negative?

Answer (score 2):

Energy is a relative quantity. This means that the change in energy $\Delta E$ is of importance. This is also the reason why $A$ can by any constant. By changing $A$, you do not change the energy difference:

$$\Delta E = E_2 - E_1 = \frac{kx_2}{2} +A - (\frac{kx_1}{2} +A) = \frac{kx_2}{2} - \frac{kx_1}{2}$$

Therefore, the minimum value of the potential energy does not have to be zero, it can be any value because A can be any value.

Comment: but if this is so then, lets say, when the spring is at equilibrium position i.e $x=0$ shouldn't the elastic potential energy stored in the spring be 0? if A can be any value then this would tell us that at $x=0$ the elastic potential energy is A and not 0, which is wrong.

Comment: The elastic potential energy is $E = kx^2/2+A$. The elastic energy stored in the system is $\Delta E = k(x_2^2-x_1^2)/2$. If you want to say something about the energy in the system, you use the second one. In your comment, you are implicitly setting equilibrium state at $x=0$ (this is, you put $x_1=0$ in the second equation) and then you compare another state. If you define the elastic potential energy to be zero at x=0, then $\Delta E = kx^2/2+A-(k0^2+A) = kx^2/2.

Answer (score 1):

$$\underline{\text{A General Discussion About Potential Energy}}$$

My answer is simply going to expand on Frederic's answer. Hopefully, observing the argument from multiple viewpoints should help in understanding.

Let's say force $\mathbf{F}$ is acting on a point mass $m$ that follows the trajectory $C$ from point $1$ to point $2$ in three dimensional space (You can think of point $1$ as labelled by $\{x_1,y_1,z_1\}$ : $\mathbf{r}_1=x_1 \hat{x} + y_1 \hat{y} +z_1\hat{z}$). In general, we have the following :
$$G(\mathbf{r}_1,\mathbf{r}_2,C)\stackrel{\text{Definition}}{:=}\int_{1\; :\; C}^2 \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r}=W_{1 \to 2 \; : \; C} \tag{1}$$

From $(1)$ you observe that the integral on the right hand side depends in general on $\mathbf{r}_1$, $\mathbf{r}_2$, and the trajectory $C$ connecting $1$ and $2$. However, there exists a special class of forces (called the conservative forces) for which the integral on the RHS of $(1)$ doesn't depend on the trajectory $C$ but only on the initial and final end points of the trajectory. If $\mathbf{F}$ is a conservative force, then we have the following :
$$G(\mathbf{r}_1, \mathbf{r}_2)=\int_{1 \;:\; \text{any $C$ connecting $1$ and $2$}}^2 \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r} \tag{2}$$

If $\mathbf{F}$ is conservative, we can show mathematically that there exists a function $U$ (called the potential energy) that obeys the following :
$$U(\mathbf{r}_1) - U(\mathbf{r}_2) = \int_{1 \;:\; \text{any $C$ connecting $1$ and $2$}}^2 \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r} \tag{3}$$

However, there is not a unique $U$ but instead a class of such $U$ each of which differ from each other by a constant. You can see this from $(3)$ : Given $U(\mathbf{r})$ satisfies $(3)$, we can see that $U'(\mathbf{r})= U(\mathbf{r})+a$ also satisfies $(3)$ since $a$ just gets cancelled by subtraction.

---

$$\underline{\text{Detour}}$$
You may wonder how $G$, which seems like an arbitrary function of 6 variables in $(2)$, can be expressed as the difference of function $U$ of 3 variables in $(3)$. For example,

$$\text{Couldn't $G$ be } G(x_1,y_1,z_1,x_2,y_2,z_2) = k(x_1x_2^2+y_1y_2^2+z_1z_2^2)\text{?}\tag{4}$$

The answer is no. To understand this, you need to realize that $G$ is not as completely arbitrary as one might think. For example, the following are two properties that $G$ must obey :
$$G(\mathbf{r}_1, \mathbf{r}_2)=\int_{1 \;:\; \text{any $C$ connecting $1$ and $2$}}^2 \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r} =-\int_{2 \;:\; \text{any $C$ connecting $1$ and $2$}}^1 \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r} = -G(\mathbf{r}_2,\mathbf{r}_2) \tag{5}$$
$$G(\mathbf{r}_1,\mathbf{r}_3)=\int_{1 \;:\; \text{any $C$ connecting $1$ and $3$}}^3 \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r}=\int_{1 \;:\; \text{any $C$ connecting $1$ and $2$}}^2 \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r} + \int_{2 \;:\; \text{any $C$ connecting $2$ and $3$}}^3 \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r}$$
$$\Rightarrow G(\mathbf{r}_1,\mathbf{r}_3)=G(\mathbf{r}_1,\mathbf{r}_2)+G(\mathbf{r}_2,\mathbf{r}_3) \tag{6}$$

---

> He then said that you can find the potential energy by doing: $\boxed{U}=-\int F\cdot dx=\int kx=\dfrac{kx^2}{2}+A$

This is not true. It is $(3)$ that is true : $\Delta U = -\int \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r}$.

How does one find the potential energy $U$ at point $\mathbf{r'}$ using $(3)$? You choose a reference point $O$ : $\mathbf{r}_O$ where you define the potential energy to be zero (Apart from certain subtleties involved which will not concern us at the moment, we can do this because we know that $U$ can changed by addition upto a constant anyway).

$$U(\mathbf{r'}) = -\int_{\mathbf{r}_O \; : \; \text{any $C$ connecting $O$ and $\mathbf{r'}$}}^{\mathbf{r'}} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r} \tag{7}$$

$$\underline{\text{Specific Example of a Conservative Force : Spring}}$$
Let's consider a spring (spring constant $k$ and free length $l$ : extension of the spring is given by $|x-l|$) placed on the x-axis with one of its end fixed to the y-z plane and the other end located at $x=l$. Now, let's attach a block to the spring and play with it. Now, in this example, it is common to choose the reference point to be $x=l$ : $U(l)=0$. This is done so that the potential energy function $U(x')$ directly gives us the work that is done by the conservative force in moving the block from $x=l$ and $x=x'$.

$$U(x') = - \int_l^{x'} k(l-x) dx = \frac{1}{2}k(x'-l)^2 \tag{8}$$

As Frederic has mentioned, the work done is related to the difference in the potential energy by $(3)$ and it is the work done that is important. The potential energy is a function to compactly encode the information of work done. The value of the potential energy function at a single point $x$ alone is useless as it doesn't tell us anything (unless the reference point is also told). If the value of $U$ at two points $x_1$ and $x_2$ are given (which is what we're implicitly doing by choosing a reference point and giving $U(x')$), then there's useful information to extract : work done by the conservative force equals $U(x_1) - U(x_2)$.

I'd advise you to read my answer multiple times to get the idea settled in mind : Everything takes time. I've avoided the use of gradients since you have mentioned that you aren't familiar with it. All the same, let me know if you have any questions in the comment and I'd be happy to help.

Comment: $U(x') = - \int_l^{x'} k(l-x) dx = \frac{1}{2}k(x'-l)^2 \tag{8}$ why is the force $k(l-x)$ shouldn't the force be $k(x-l)$?

Comment: do you have any suggestions for a good book or reference to get me started on potential energies,work done, and energy conservations that doesn't necessary include vector calculus?

Comment: @LucaIon I chose $k(l-x)$ in $(8)$ because the $F$ in $\Delta U = -\int F dx$ is the conservative force pointing in positive $x$ direction. When $x<l$, we see that the spring is compressed and that means the spring exerts a force to the right (positive direction) on the block. And when $x>l$  the spring is stretched and it will exert a force to the left (negative) on the block.

Comment: I was introduced to these concepts when I first read H. C. Verma's Concepts of Physics (Part 1) : It doesn't have advanced vector calculus and it has good explanations. You can try reading that book. Feynman's lectures are also an alternative. However, I'd strongly advise you to learn and get comfortable with vector calculus. What I've said in my answer can be shortened to the following statement : $\mathbf{F}$ is conservative $\Leftrightarrow$ there exists a function $U(\mathbf{r})$ such that $\mathbf{F}=-\nabla U$ .